# Excel count number of items in a multiline cell that match a text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to Excel function.  I have an Excel worksheet that has two columns.  Column A contains the model of a main network switch.  Column B contains the stacked switches and network modules below.

Each cell in Column B is a **MULTILINE** cell. See example below.

**Please note:** I can't create a table in here to show **MULTILINE** cell. In cell C1, I write a function to count only the number of switch model C9300-24 and C9300-48, but the result is 0.  Can someone help to suggest a function that can count number of stacked switches in Column B. I don't want to count the ntwork module (C9300-NM-10G).  Thank you in advance.

| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C9300-24 | C9300-24 | =COUNTIF(B1, "C9300-24") |
|  | C9300-NM-10G |  |
|  | C9300-24 |  |
|  | C9300-NM-10G |  |
|  | C9300-48 |  |
|  | C9300-NM-10G |  |

Comment: What is the expected result? 2 (because C9300-24 is a duplicate) or 3? If the latter, maybe this could work: `=SUM(--(LEFT(TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10)),"-"),2)<>"NM"))`. Please describe more accurately what it is you want to count.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, just made it bit shorter: `=SUM(--(RIGHT(TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10)),2)={"24";"48"}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEN` to count the number of characters in B1

`SUBSTITUTE` to replace the string with blanks, and `LEN` to count the number of characters again.

Subtract those two to see how many characters were replaced, divide that by the `LEN` of characters in your string, and the result is how many times the string was found.

```
=(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")))/LEN(A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, however in terms of readability and simplicity, we can use `TEXTSPLIT()` & `SUM()` function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10))=A1))
```

---

- `TEXTSPLIT()` function splits the cells column wise using the delimiter as line-feed( note that it has been assumed since the post says about `MULTILINE` cells.) therefore `CHAR(10)` is represents line-feed.
- Checking `--(TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10))=A1)` whether it meets the match or not, if it does it returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` for non match converting them to `1` & `0` using double unary, basically we are doing a boolean logic check.
- Last but not least using `SUM()` function to sum above output.

---

Another alternative :

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(A1,TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10))))
```

---

If the count is required for both the switch model starting with `C9300` & ending with `24` & `48` then one could try: (instead of using this `{24;48}` I have used `{1;2}*24`.

[image]

---

```
=SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10),,1)="C9300-"&{1;2}*24))
```

---

Or, need is unique count then

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10),,1)="C9300-"&{1;2}*24,1)))
```

---